# how to loop through dictionary keys and compare to my Integer in swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, dictionary, compare

I have a quick question about how to loop through a dictionary key and compare its key to my integer, then print out the corresponding value if the key exists.

For example, this is my code

```
for(var j = 0; j <= someDictionary.count; j++) {
    if ( someInteger == someDictionary.keys[j] ) {
        someDictioanrysValue = someDictionary.values[j]
        println(someDictioanrysValue)
    }
}
```

is there a method in dictionary that does what I want already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you're just looking to use the subscript - no `for` loops required.

```
let dict = [1: "A", 3: "B", 5: "C"]
let myInt = 3

if let value = dict[myInt] {
    print(value)
}

// Prints: B
```

If a value doesn't exist for the key you supplied, `nil` will be returned and so the code inside the `if let` won't be executed.

If you're unfamiliar with this I'd really recommend you take a look at [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/).

Comment: Hey ABakerSmith thanks for the quick reply! I apologize if my question seemed confusing but what I am asking is that if I have a dictionary dict of [Int: String], and I have an Integer int, if dict's got a matching key to int (comparison here using if), then I want to print out that dict's value (dict[int])

Comment: Did you try my example? That should do what you want :)